# If I use my parents' address as my permanent address, can I get renters insurance at a different address?

Tags: california, insurance

Is it possible to have insurance at multiple locations?

I use my parents' address as my permanent address, because I move quite often (within state - close to home), and it's a pain to have to change my address all the time. Additionally, because there are several people listed at that address for car insurance, there's some kind of discount, and my bill is significantly lower than it would be if I re-registered my car every time I moved. In case of emergency, and logically, that is my truest "permanent address."

I rent a room at a house in a different city closeby. I would like to get renters' insurance, but I'm wondering if registering that would conflict with my permanent address, car insurance, etc. So far, I haven't had any issues with credit or getting into an apartment. I do almost all of my bills paperless. When I lived out-of-state, I registered everything myself at the address where I was, so this is kind of a new experience and I haven't had renter's insurance for the past 2 years.

State is California.

Answer (score 1):

Probably.

In practice it is the insurance companies that determine the answer to such questions.  By law they do so in compliance with the rules and regulations for insuring in the state, which few consumers could possibly navigate on their own.

It is a crime to conceal or alter facts they request for determining what, if any, insurance policies they will sell you, and at what rate.  So shop for the insurance you want, answer underwriting questions truthfully, and you'll have your answer.  If you believe something is amiss, you can appeal to [the state insurance commission](http://www.insurance.ca.gov/).